# Clonezilla 2tb disk used 20gb to 16gb usb

Tags: partitioning, backup, clonezilla

I am pretty new to Clonzilla, so I have 2tb hdd which has fresh os install currently used space is 18.1Gb. Just a 10 minute ago I create backup with clonezilla to a 16gb flashdisk and it just takes 6.8 of place.

1. Am I doing something wrong I just wanted to test and it completed
   with no error
2. I use save disk image option
3. If what I have done is wrong what should be the proper way? (I was thinking to partition used area and just backup this partition using compression?)
4. There is a big documentation I know but the small advice will be
   valuable that I wonder if I can use this backed up image after I
   format the disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clonezilla uses on-the-fly compression by default. If you haven't choosen the advanced mode, then your image is probably compressed with gzip. You can confirm it by opening the Clonezilla image's directory and looking for files with extension `.gz` or `.gz.00` (or `.bz2`/`.bz2.00` if bzip2 compression was used).

Comment: gronostaj is correct, many disk imagers/cloners will include an option to compress the image. Note that like with any compression, the resulting size will depend entirely on the contents of the disk. If your 18.1GB disk compressed down to 6.1GB, then that drive had a lot of fairly compressible files to achieve a ⅓ compression ratio.